# For the Fourier transform, when simplifying an integral's bounds by ignoring where half of it equals 0, why don't we divide by two?

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

For example: I need to do a Fourier Transform on f(t)*h(t), h(t) is 1 for t>0 and 0 for t <0, the answers for several questions end up using the usual formula but integrate from 0 to infinity which is fine, however should we not divide by 2 to account for the -infinity to 0 part of the function?

I have done many similar questions recently in learning the Fourier Series and when simplifying the integral in a similar fashion, we ALWAYS divided by two.

Example:[image]

Answer (score 0):

In previous cases where you have seen a factor of $2$ or $\tfrac12$, there must have been a **reason** for that – some symmetry perhaps, but it's impossible to say for sure, since you haven't given any examples. But the reason cannot have been *only* that the interval of integration was cut in half. You must also take into account what function you are integrating.

Anyway, in this case here, the transform is
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \, h(t) \, e^{-it\omega} dt
&=
\int_{-\infty}^0 f(t) \, h(t) \, e^{-it\omega} dt
+
\int_{0}^\infty f(t) \, h(t) \, e^{-it\omega} dt
\\ &
=
\int_{-\infty}^0 f(t) \cdot 0 \cdot e^{-it\omega} dt
+
\int_{0}^\infty f(t) \cdot 1 \cdot e^{-it\omega} dt
\\ &
=
0 + \int_{0}^\infty f(t) \, e^{-it\omega} dt
,
\end{split}
$$
so there is no division by two.

Comment: Thankyou, I edited my question to include an example.

Comment: @ramose: OK. But that example is about computing a Fourier **series**, not a Fourier **transform**. And the reason for writing $a_0/2$ instead of $a_0$ is just to enable the same formula to be used for all $a_n$ (including $n=0$), by compensating for the fact that $\cos(0x)$ has average $1$ while $\cos(nx)$ with $n \ge 1$ has average $1/2$. The factor of $1/2$ in $a_0/2$ has nothing whatsoever to do with $f$ being zero on half the interval!

Comment: See here, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161147/why-does-a-fourier-series-have-a-1-2-in-front-of-the-a-0-coefficient